# Python requests module get function

Tags: python, python-requests

I have written a small script in Python and executing it on Windows is fine. I got no errors. In Windows my Python version is 3.5.

I have tried to execute the same program on Ubuntu, Python 3.4 but, but I am getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "urlscript.py", line 356, in <module>
    postcheck[dc]()
  File "urlscript.py", line 17, in DC8Prod
    pmlogin(url,payload)
  File "urlscript.py", line 254, in pmlogin
    mainpage=requests.get(url,payload)
TypeError: get() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Comment: Watch at get() function. You gave his 2 arguments, but he wants only one.

Comment: What version of `requests` is installed on Ubuntu, what version on Windows? If `payload` is a dictionary with query parameters, `query=payload` instead of a positional argument.

Comment: @valex But I didnt get any issues with windows

Comment: @MartijnPieters I am not sure of version but I pulled with pip3

Comment: @Raja: `pip3 freeze` will show you the versions of all your packages installed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only `url` is really supported as a positional argument; for a `GET` request with query parameters, use `params` as the keyword argument:

```
mainpage = requests.get(url, params=payload)
```

See [*Passing Parameters In URLs*](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart/#passing-parameters-in-urls).

A recent release of `requests` (2.7.0 or newer), made `params` an explicit argument to the `requests.get()` function, making it possible to use it as a positional parameter too. Your version on Ubuntu must be older than that.